# Thread Safe window positioning

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to find a way to do a thread-safe manipulation for positioning a form. I created a thread to change the position of a form when it is shown and to abort it when it is not shown. This works up until I try to change the position. I tried googling a thread-safe way to change the position of a window but couldn't find anything that worked well enough.

I checked around stack overflow but may not have been searching for the proper thread. I have also searched google with the same issue.

```
Form1 form;
IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, WINDOW_NAME);
RECT rect;
Thread posThread;

public FormOverlay(Form1 _form) {
    InitializeComponent();

    form = _form;
    posThread = new Thread(move);
}

private void FormOverlay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GetWindowRect(handle, out rect);

    this.Size = new Size(rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);

    posThread.Start();
}

public struct RECT {
    public int left, top, right, bottom;
}

public void move() {
    while(form.isChecked()) { // Checkbox in another window
        this.Top = rect.top;
        this.Left = rect.left;

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

I get

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'FormOverlay' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: `Thread Safe window positioning` there is none, you need to do all this stuff on the main ui thread, or marshal back to it

Comment: Thank you @TheGeneral and John ! This solved my issue, the code ended up looking like this https://pastebin.com/BJk1xVPf

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop or threads to solve this problem, Winforms is a Event based system so use it to your advantage. The event [`Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.move?view=netframework-4.7.2) will be called when the form is moved and you can put your code in there.

You may want to also subscribe to [`CheckedChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) and have that fire the move code too to update the window position when the box is initially checked.

```
public FormOverlay(Form1 _form) {
    InitializeComponent();

    form = _form;
    form.SomeCheckbox.CheckedChanged += OnSomeCheckboxChanged
    this.Move += OnMove;
}

private void FormOverlay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GetWindowRect(handle, out rect);

    this.Size = new Size(rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
}

public struct RECT {
    public int left, top, right, bottom;
}

private void OnSomeCheckboxChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
   DoMove();
}

private void OnMove(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
   DoMove();
}

private void DoMove();
    if (form.isChecked()) { // Checkbox in another window
        this.Top = rect.top;
        this.Left = rect.left;
    }
}
```